# Change location of save folder in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am fairly new to SharePoint and I have written an application where a document is downloaded when I click a button however when I download the document it is automatically saved in the bin folder how can I change where the document is saved to?

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var site = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
    {
        var web = site.RootWeb;
        var docLibFileUrl = "http://foo/demo/SharePointTest/Test.docx";
        var localFileName = "Test.docx";

        SPFile spFile = web.GetFile(docLibFileUrl);
        FileStream outStream = new FileStream(localFileName, FileMode.Create);
        byte[] fileData = spFile.OpenBinary();
        outStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Count());
        outStream.Close();        
    }

    listBox1.Items.Add("Document downloaded");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code like the following

```
string tempPath = "C:\\TempFolder";

Byte[] tempFile = file.OpenBinary();

if (tempFile.Length>=0)
{
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
  fs.Write(tempFile, 0, tempFile.Length);
  fs.Close();
}
```

Or you can use the approach from this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/62803eb3-430e-4ede-b649-bc9de4dbdd69).

Comment: Thanks for this! It was just what I needed. Sorry about the delay getting back to you!